# Put value from view in viewBag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a hidden field in my HTML view

```
<%:Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ContactId) %>
```

I want to put this value in viewBag so that I can use it in controller. How to do that? Also, how will I access this in controller?

Comment: You're putting it in the Model then it'll be available in the Controller. What doesn't work?

Comment: It should be working by accessing `model.ContactId`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have the notion of `postback` in ASP.NET MVC and the `ViewBag` is available to you to deliver data to the view, but not to transfer data back and forth between the view and the controller.

If your hidden input is in a form then upon posting the form the new value would be accessible via `model.ContactId`.

Example:

```
// Model
class TestModel
{
     public string ContactId { get; set; }
}

//Controller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(TestModel model)
{
    string newId = model.ContactId;
}
```

Comment: No callback function. I have pass this value on grid load.